# To display data using cursors in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written this code to 'display the department names from department table using cursors'

```
declare
v_dname department.department_name%type;
cursor dept_cursor is select department_name from department;
begin
open dept_cursor;
loop
fetch dept_cursor into v_dname;
exit
when dept_cursor%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line('Department names are :' || v_dname);
end loop;
close dept_cursor;
end;
/
```

This code runs fine and shows shows 'the procedure is created', but the output values are not being displayed. I tried running the 'dbms_output.put_line' statement alone, it worked. I don't know what else to check. Please help, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`? If not *literally*, then enable it in your GUI. Because, code itself looks (and works) OK. I don't have your table, but Scott's `DEPT` is OK for testing as well.

Your code, unmodified (apart from `DEPARTMENT` being changed to `DEPT`):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on                  --> did you do this?
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2     v_dname  dept.dname%type;
  3
  4     cursor dept_cursor is select dname from dept;
  5  begin
  6     open dept_cursor;
  7
  8     loop
  9        fetch dept_cursor into v_dname;
 10
 11        exit when dept_cursor%notfound;
 12        dbms_output.put_line ('Department names are :' || v_dname);
 13     end loop;
 14
 15     close dept_cursor;
 16  end;
 17  /
Department names are :ACCOUNTING
Department names are :RESEARCH
Department names are :SALES
Department names are :OPERATIONS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

If it still doesn't work, check whether table contains any rows.

---

One more thing: you said

> This code runs fine and shows shows '**the procedure is created**'

This isn't actually an Oracle message so I'm not sure whether I'm interpreting it correctly, but: if you actually created a *stored procedure* (what you posted is an *anonymous PL/SQL block*), message says `Procedure created`. It, furthermore, means that you have to actually **execute** it to get some result.

For example, if procedure's name was `p_show_dept`, you'd

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> begin              --> executing the procedure
  2    p_show_dept;
  3  end;
  4  /

Department names are :ACCOUNTING
Department names are :RESEARCH
Department names are :SALES
Department names are :OPERATIONS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I had not created any extra procedure of my own, the table is all pre-existing. Hence I don't have a name for the procedure too. So just the `set serveroutput on` works. I didn't notice that since I used `insert` statements to output till now. Thank you so much for your time and help! :)